# Is it Illegal to break out of a forum post by using CSS for example?

Tags: exploit, xss, legal

Is it illegal in the UK to post styling that breaks out of a post?

For instance, if styling were allowed here and I were to use it to change some stackexchange pictures on this page, would that be illegal?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking or why this would be illegal anywhere.  Are you talking about xss?

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, the [Computer Misuse Act of 1990](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1990/18/contents) does make this illegal if you do anything on the server:

Section 1 of the act makes **unauthorised access to computer material** a criminal act, punishable by 6 months' imprisonment or a fine "not exceeding level 5 on the standard scale" (currently £5000)

This is a very wide-reaching act, and is a major reason for some of the disclaimers security testing companies require, as it doesn't even require you to change anything - simply accessing the computer system or data can be enough.

If you are simply doing it on your own computer, replacing images or content as you see it, you should have no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about code injections. Injecting your own random style code into a website might violate the websites Terms Of Use, so you can get in trouble that way, but (in some countries) there is no explicit law that says you cannot do this sort of stuff.

Comment: Some countries have laws against this, like the UK.

Comment: In Germany someone injected a link into the web forum of a political party, which pointed to another political party. This was obviously just a prank and the attacker could have cause real damage. Nonetheless the person was sentenced to pay a quite high fine